# How to extract a particular word after 7th slash in a path using regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have different paths in a column like below:

```
'E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM//Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Austria/Toothpaste/Variant Data/AUSTRIA_SHG_VARIANT_8.csv'
'E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM//Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Austria/ManualTB/Variant Data/AUSTRIA_SHG_VARIANT_7.csv'
'E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM//Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Austria/MouthWash/Variant Data/AUSTRIA_SHG_VARIANT_9.csv'
```

I want Toothpaste from 1st path, ManualTB from 2nd, and MouthWash from 3rd.

There are many more paths around 30 every from every paths I want the word from 7th slash.

How can I do this using regex?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, what have you tried?

Comment: This would be better done with a tool that understand's paths (eg. PowerShell's `Split-Path`) than with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?:\/([^\/\n]*)){7}
```

Check [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ye8y2/1)

Required keywords would be in capture group 1

Comment: its giving me error like this   [ Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?:\/" ]

Comment: @shantammalgaonkar Which editor/language are you using? you can try this one.. without escape characters: `(?:/([^/\n]*)){7}`

Comment: using R studio to extract the word i mentioned

Comment: now its showing me this error -{Error in stri_extract_last_regex(employ.data$Path, "(?:/([^/\n]*)){7}") : 
  could not find function "stri_extract_last_regex"}

Comment: @shantammalgaonkar Can you verify the output of `stri_install_check(silent=TRUE)` in your code?.. it should return `true`

Comment: employ.data$Extract =stri_extract_last_regex(employ.data$Path, "(?:/([^/\n]*)){7}")     i am susing this line where i am creating new column extract and taking the words from the Path column

Answer (score 0):

You can match any optional characters followed by a slash and capture the word following it by using this regex,

```
(?:.*?\/){7}(\w+)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?:.*?\/){7}` --> Non capture group matching any optional characters followed by `/` seven times
- `(\w+)` --> Capture the following word in group 1

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J6ZKDM/1)

Let me know if this works fine for you.

Comment: Showing me this error   Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?:.*?\/"

Comment: Can you try this regex (?:.*?\Q/\E){7}([a-zA-Z]+) and see if it works? I will update my answer if this works. I never programmed in R language so not sure if slash further needs double escaping or there is some other issue.

Comment: showing me this error [Error: '\Q' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "" (?:.*?\Q"]